# Universal Cross-platform GUI for Python Scripts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, gtk

Is there a way to create a GUI for Python scripts that works on Mac, Windows and Linux?

There surely must be a universal way.

Anyone having an Idea? What about GTK? Any good alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default way to make GUI applications with python is using the `tkinter` module https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#module-tkinter

If however `tkinter` does not meet your needs, there are several non-standard libraries which can be found here https://docs.python.org/3/faq/gui.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Kivy](https://kivy.org/), is a cross-platform GUI for Python, could be used on Mac, Windows, Linux, Android, iOS.